# What's the difference between using all(calendar) vs filter(all(calendar, ..)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

To remove the Calendar from the context, I see there are 2 options.

1. Calculate(...,all(calendar))
2. Calculate(...,filter(all(calendar,..)))

I understand that option 1 is same as using REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDAR)

What's the difference between option 1 and option 2.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases `all` removes any outer filters on `calendar`.  So in the first case the expression is calculated over all `calendar` rows, in the second case it is calculated over all `calendar` rows that satisfy the predicate you pass as the second argument to `filter`.

See generally

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculate-in-dax/

and

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/

Comment: But doesn't filter ALL result in pulling entire calendar table thus reduce performance? If not then in which scenario does this issue happen?

Comment: With ALL the calculation in the first argument to calculate will remove filters on the calendar table, which would otherwise have limited how many rows in related tables referenced by the calculation would need to be scanned.  So perhaps.